# What does 臉盆 "washbasin" mean when it's part of the names of dishes in Taiwan?

Tags: meaning-in-context, food, taiwan

A restaurant just up the road from my hostel here in Taichung, Taiwan has some dishes including the characters  臉盆. When I looked them up I could only find the meaning "washbasin". Even hunting the internet afterwards I couldn't find any other meaning or useful reference to food.

[image: 臉盆 section of the menu]

What could 臉盆 mean in this context?

Comment: This is an example of where plugging Chinese words into Google Image Search works really well.

Comment: @BenJackson: I did try that and I got pictures of actual washbasins. I also tried to combine this word with various food words and the word Taiwan. Some looked like food but I wouldn't have guessed conclusively that it came down to type or size of bowl. Moreover none of the hits seemed to be articles about the concept.

Comment: Wow there are some great image results for 脸盆泡菜你哦肉面 with people in front of giant basins of food.

Comment: @BenJackson: Ah well that's one string I didn't try. My Chinese is not that good so I have to enter most characters by drawing on my phone screen, which I can't do on the laptop. And anyhow not enough for me personally to put together that "wash basin" = "large soup bowl" on my own.

Comment: https://www.mdbg.net/ can look up characters by drawing when you don't have your phone handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

臉盆 still means *washbasin* here, it's just that *this* washbasin is a very large bowl used for food.

A tonne more noodles and a lot more soup.

Comment: You can say wash basin size is another words for super jumbo size

Comment: Like a "Bucket" of KFC?